# sequelize create records with foreign key

Tags: sequelize.js

Lets say the condition is user has many projects

```
var User = sequelize.define('user', {
  id: { type: Sequelize.INTEGER, primaryKey: true},
  name: Sequelize.STRING,
}, {
  underscored: true,
  constraints: false
})

var Project = sequelize.define('project', {
  id: { type: Sequelize.INTEGER, primaryKey: true},
  title: Sequelize.STRING,
}, {
  underscored: true,
  constraints: false
})

Project.belongsTo(User)
User.hasMany(Project)
```

If I already I have a record of user in DB

```
{ id: 1, name: "spondbob" }
```

How do I create a project with that user? I have seen somewhere that we can do this when create a project

```
{
  id: 1,
  title: "Project 1",
  user_id: 1
}
```

But is there like an elegant way to set the user other than directly mentioning the foreign key?

Also I know that I can just create the project and do `project.setUser(user)` but the problem is the `user_id` foreign key is set to NOT NULL. In that case I have to add the `user_id` when I create project, not set it after the creation.

To add that, if I need to create and assign multiple projects to a user, how can I achieve one?

Comment: You won't be able to create a new `Project` and link to an existing association in one step. You'll have to do `Project.create(obj)` and in the callback run `projectInstance.setUser(user)`

Comment: @mcranston18 If I do `Project.create(obj)` without mentioning the foreign key `user_id`, my db engine will throw an error as the foreign key is set to NOT NULL. I don't think removing NOT NULL constraint is a good idea only to be able to do `projectInstance.setUser(user)` later on.

Comment: Did you find a solution?

Answer (score 0):

```
{
  id: 1,
  title: "Project 1",
  user_id: 1
}
```

The code above just works if you had specified the Foreign Key name as the follow:

```
Project.belongsTo(User, {foreignKey: 'user_id'})
```